# what is the total number of seating arrangements

Tags: combinatorics

each of 16 students has a ticket to one chair in a row at a theater how many ways are there to seat the students so that each student sits in the specified on his or her chair or in the one right next to it? 
each chair is to be occupied by exactly one student.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. What have you tried so far? Why is your question tagges as real-analysis? This sound more like combinatorics.

Comment: I found out that $n$ persons can be seated in $f(n)$ ways and $(n-1)$ in $f(n-1)$ ways.

Comment: Consider the leftmost seat, Seat 1. Either (i) it is occupied by the "correct" person or (ii) it is occupied by the person assigned Seat 2, in which case Seat 2 must be occupied by the person assigned Seat 1. Use these observations to obtain a familiar recurrence for $f$.  Finish by finding $f(1)$ and $f(2)$.

Answer (score 1):

let's say $a_{n}$ - the number of options to seat n students in a row, in their place or one of the places right next to it.

let's look at the student who has the ticket in the first seat.
he can be seated in two options:
in his original seat, and then you have $a_{n-1}$ ways to seat the others.
in the next seat, but then he has to switch places with the student who had this seat originally, because someone has to occupy the original first seat. so in this case you have got $a_{n-2}$ ways to seat the students.

in total:

$a_{n} = a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}$

$a_{0} = 1, a_{1} = 1$

and you get the fibonacci, with its index indented by one.
The general expression for nth students will be: 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}((\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^{n+1} - (\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^{n+1})$$

if n=16, the final answer will be 1597.